# How to transition between notes in Bansuri

Tags: notation, indian-classical, articulation, bansuri, saptak

Ok, at this point, I am teaching myself Bansuri (A Scale) by playing simple tunes 10-15 min a day (totally swamped nowadays)

Playing [Om Jai Jagdish Hare](http://www.hemantsharmakaushik.com/2018/04/om-jai-jagdish-hare-aarti-notes-sargam.html) it quite straightforward (plus I am familiar with [the tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ucCEjXS9n8))

But how can I play [Satyam Shivam Sundaram](https://www.notesandsargam.com/satyam-shivam-sundaram/)

I am very familiar with [this melody](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdU3qP5EYoY), but how do I do the following, i.e.

`Ishwar | satya | hai
 M~G G  | g S   | S~g`

In other words, how do I transition between notes when there is `~`

And how to treat notes that are between brackets `()` and curly braces `{}`

Please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I have to tell you that I'm for sure not an expert at Bansuri's :P

However, when you say that ~ is transitioning between two notes, it's basically legato. So you just want to go from one note into the other. You can achieve this by covering the holes slowly. Just watch this video from the point I set it to. First he plays the notes by covering the holes quickly like you probably do it. Right after he plays it again with a slower finger motion, which covers the holes more slowly. This gives the feeling that the note blend into each other: [Note transition](https://youtu.be/lQUg7KGxYwI?t=183)

The other question about the brackets... As far as I know are brackets in Bansuri grace notes. So if the notes are like "S (R) G" it means that the R is a grace note. A grace note is just a very quickly played note which you basically achieve by just covering the hole for a split-second on and off.