# How to use Meend in Bansuri Playing

Tags: technique, indian-classical, ornaments, bansuri

I am following tutorial to play Om Jai Jagdish Hare.

The gentleman says we can use Meend in Bansuri. He explains it is a soft way to go from one note to the next.

How would I do it.

The video starts playing at 2:39

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As he demonstrates in the video ['meend'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meend) is the slight slide or glissando between notes you can get by placing the finger on the hole slowly or removing it slowly. This is typical of the Indian playing style.

It's a specific, more extreme, form of 'legato' which is a general term referring to any kind of soft transition from one note to another.

Comment: So it is a matter of practice then. Have to practice slow-and-steady

Comment: @Marium Yes, plenty of practice. Play along with the video and try to match his sound

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the term 'Meend' but I'm pretty sure 'legato' is what you're looking for.

Legato just means to transition smoothly between two notes, so that you basically fade from one note into another one.

I just answered a similar question a couple weeks ago. You may look into this thread, since I think this answers your question as well: [How to transition between notes in Bansuri](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/85473/how-to-transition-between-notes-in-bansuri/85508#85508)

Comment: 'Legato' is a much more general term. Here he's talking about something more specific to the bansuri

Comment: Yes glissando is closest. Very visible in [sitar](https://youtu.be/XaiDt6JPxaU) when the string is pulled on a fret. (not the oscillatory movements ie vibrato (andolan) but the slower unidirectional ones)